# What is the Review approve event in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, review

I need to send an offer email to customers, if their review is approved.

I can't find one. How can I list all the events available in Magento?

**What hook/event can I use?**

In Magento 1.9 version:

```
<?>
    <observers>
        <your_module>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>your_module/observer</class>
            <method>yourMethod</method>
        </your_module>
    </observers>
</?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated by Rakesh, the `review_save_after` is the event you need.

However, **this will be triggered whenever you save a review even if you don't approve it.**

Thus in your observer you need to check if the review is being approved:

```
$review = $observer->getDataObject();

// Check if there are changes
if ($review->hasDataChanges()) {
    // Get the old status
    $oldStatus = $review->getOrigData('status_id');
    // Get the new status
    $newStatus = $review->getData('status_id');
    // Check if they are different and if the new one is approved
    if ($newStatus != $oldStatus && $newStatus == Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED) {
        // Send email to customer
    }
}
```

Comment: i added the event in admin         <review_save_after>
            <observers> ... it don't trigger

Comment: @manokarthickkarthick how do you know it's not triggered ?

Comment: by    var_dump($review);exit; in my observer function.  it doesn't exited, just runs as usual

Comment: @manokarthickkarthick what if you call `Mage::log("test");` instead of `var_dump($review);exit;` and check your `var/log/system.log` file ?

Comment: it don't create any log

Comment: it fine , i found a typo in config

Comment: @manokarthickkarthick glad you fixed it

Answer (score 2):

you can try with **`<review_save_after>`**

```
<review_save_after>
 <observers>
      <your_module>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>your_module/observer</class>
        <method>yourMethod</method>
      </your_module>
    </observers>
</review_save_after>
```

Comment: will it work from admin also?

Comment: Type is singleton by default, doesn't need to be specified

Comment: i havent try with may be its working after save using admin, This is the main event of review so its working